# Augmenting a matrix by filling missing entries

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

Suppose I have a $2\times 4$ matrix like the following:

```
sampledata = {{1, , 1, 0}, {0, 1, , 1}};
```

It's a binary zero or one entry matrix. And as you can see, the cell `{1, 2}` and `{2, 3}` are empty.

What I want to do is to fill up the missing entries with all possible combinations of zeroes and ones.

So, the final matrix should look like

```
updateddata = {{1, 1, 1, 0},{1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

How should I proceed to get the augmented matrix of the final form?

---

Thank you for your comments. But I found the functions suggested works only when there are at most one missing entries in each row..

I should update my example. The matrix is

`sampledata1 = {{1,,,0},{0,,1,1}}`

That has two missing entries in the first row and one missing entry in the second row. So there are $2^3$ possibilities to fill in the missing entries that makes the final matrix look like

`updateddata1 = {{1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1},{1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1}}`

Comment: shouldn't `updateddata1` be `{{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}} `?

Comment: @kglr there are 3 missing entries for the binary elements. So, there should be $2^3$ cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to do it, but I find this the easiest to parse:

```
Flatten[Table[Replace[m, Null -> b, 1],
              {m, {{1, , 1, 0}, {0, 1, , 1}}}, {b, {1, 0}}], 1]
   {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}
```

---

The OP's new example requires a slightly different approach:

```
sample = {{1, , , 0}, {0, , 1, 1}};
pos = Position[sample, Null];

Flatten[Table[ReplacePart[sample, Thread[pos -> t]], {t, Tuples[{1, 0}, {3}]}], 1]
   {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[replaceNulls] 
replaceNulls = Module[{pos = Flatten@Position[#, Null], lst = #}, 
    Table[SubsetMap[t &, lst, pos], {t, Tuples[{1, 0}, Length@pos]}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
sampledata = {{1, , 1, 0}, {0, 1, , 1}};

Catenate @ Map[replaceNulls] @ sampledata
```

.      {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}

```
sampledata2 = {{1, , , 0}, {0, 1, , 1}} ;

Catenate @ Map[replaceNulls] @ sampledata2
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0},
>  {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}
> ```

**Original answer:** Works when each input list has a single `Null`:

We can use `ReplaceAll` with a *list of lists of rules*:

```
ReplaceAll[{{Null -> 1}, {Null -> 0}}] /@ sampledata
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}}
> ```

```
Join @@ %  (* or Catenate @ % *)
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}
> ```

Or combine the two steps:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Catenate @* Map[ReplaceAll[{{Null -> 1}, {Null -> 0}}]];

f @ sampledata
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}
> ```

More generally,

```
vlist = {v1, v2, v3};

ReplaceAll[List /@ Thread[Null -> vlist]] /@ sampledata
```

> ```
>  {{{1, v1, 1, 0}, {1, v2, 1, 0}, {1, v3, 1, 0}},
>   {{0, 1, v1, 1}, {0, 1, v2, 1}, {0, 1, v3, 1}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But I found this function only works when there is at most one missing entry in each row.. For example, when ```sampledata = {{1, , , 0}, {0, 1, , 1}};```, it still produces ```{{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}}``` that has only 4 rows.. instead of 8 rows that contains all possible combinations of zeroes and ones for the missing entries.

Comment: You should put that example in your question @Andean, that requires something completely different.

Comment: @J.M., Yeah, I should've done that from the beginning. I've updated the question.